# Trouble in finding number of permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am currently taking a course on Discrete Mathematics. In that while solving this problem am bit confused with the method of solving the following problem.

> Problem: How many arrangements are there of the letters
>   **TALLAHASSEE** which have no adjacent A's?

I can find the total number of permutations. But How to find the total no of permutations of adjacent A's?

so that, my answer will be..

> Answer = total number of all permutations  - total number of permutations of adjacent A's

Comment: Find the total permutations, then subtract from it the number of permutations with adjacent As.

Answer (score 6):

We can bypass Inclusion/Exclusion by using a minor modification of [Stars and Bars.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)

First arrange the $8$ non-A's.  The number of arrangements is the multinomial coefficient
$$\binom{8}{2,2,2,1,1}.$$
Alternately, put a sticker on one of the two L, one of the two S, and one of the two E, to distinguish them. The $8$ distinct letters can be arranged in $8!$ ways. Remove the stickers, one at a time. Each time we remove a sticker, $2!$ arrangements collapse into $1$. So the number of arrangements of the $8$ letters is
$$\frac{8!}{2!2!2!}.$$

The $8$ letters determine $9$ "**holes**," one at the left end, one at the right end, and seven inter-letter holes. We need to *choose* $3$ of these holes to put the A's into. This can be done in $\binom{9}{3}$ ways.

It follows that the number of words with no two A's adjacent is
$$\binom{8}{2,2,2,1,1}\binom{9}{3} \qquad\text{or equivalently}\qquad\frac{8!}{2!2!2!}\binom{9}{3} .$$

Compute. We get $(5040)(84)$, which is $423360$.

**Comment**: In the same way, we can get a simple *expression* for the answer if there are many more letters, including many more A's.  Inclusion/Exclusion also generalizes, but gets gradually more unpleasant.

Comment: +1 for adding and removing "sticker"! and +100 for the rest! Superb approach! :)

Answer (score 5):

There are total 11 characters, 3 "A", 2 "L", 2 "S", 2 "E", and one "T" and one "H". The total number of unrestricted permutations $n_0$ would be $n_0 =\binom{11}{3,2,2,2,1,1}=\frac{11!}{3! (2!)^3} = 831600$.

Now, replace a pair of "A" characters with a double $\tilde{A}$. Number of permutations here $n_1 =\binom{10}{1,1,2,2,2,1,1} = 453600$.

Replacing a triple of "A" with a single character gets $n_2 = \binom{9}{1,2,2,2,1,1} = 45360$.

The number of permutations with no adjacent "A"s is obtained by inclusion-exclusion principle $n = n_0 - n_1 + n_2 = 423360$.

Here is *Mathematica* explicit counting:

```
In[3]:= Length@
 DeleteCases[
  Permutations[Characters["TALLAHASSEE"]], {___, "A", "A", ___}]

Out[3]= 423360
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the number in which the `A`s are adjacent, put them together and treat it like a unit!

If two `A`s are together, you are finding permutations of the letters T, L, L, H, S, S, a letter called `AA`, and a letter called `A`. You have to be careful, though, since you will be counting instances in which `A` goes first and `AA` goes immediately after as different from those in which `AA` goes first and `A` goes immediately after, whereas they are the same. So you need to "take out" from the count those permutations in which all three `A`s are together. How to count them?

Treat the three like a unit! Now you want to count the number of permutations of the letters T, L, L, H, S, S, and a letter called `AAA`.

So: your total should be:

(Total number) - (count with a letter `AA` and a letter `A`) + (count with a letter `AAA`).