# Finding the Total number of permutation using a selective formula

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, factorial

I am a python programmer,trying to upgrade a python program I created.

I am aware the total number of permutations can be calculated using

```
n^r
```

where n is the total number of things to choose from and r is how many we choose..

**for example consider the string "abc" where need to generate three letter "words"..the result  below**

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb
abc
aca
acb
acc
baa
bab
bac
bba
bbb
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

**Question**

What I am trying to accomplish is to derive a formula for the total number of permutations where each permutation has maximum nth characters of the same identity..consider this example

for example the total number of permutations that has only **two letters** of the same type repeating....

This is my results for generating all permutations from my program with two letters of the same type reaming

```
aab - only two 'a'
aac - only two 'a'
aba - onyl two 'a'
abb - only two 'b'
abc - maximum is two letters repeating..also good
aca - maximum is two letters repeating..also good
acb - maximum is two letters repeating..also good
acc - maximum is two letters repeating..also good
baa- .maximum is two letters repeating..also good
bab ..................
bac....................
bba
bbc
bca
bcb
bcc
caa
cab
cac
cba
cbb
cbc
cca
ccb
```

**TOTAL NUMBER OF PERMUTATION IS 24**
I can't seem to derive a way to do this BEFORE outputing the results..

**In a nutshell**

I want to find A FORMULA for the number of permutation that only has nth letters in each permutation repeating not more than nth of the same type..

I want to precalculate the **total number of permutations** where each permutation has nth letter of the same type remaining and output this to the user of my program

---

My program is bulky but here is the permutation codes I am using (note I am using itertools from python built in libraries)

```
for perm in itertools.product(string,repeat=self.word_length):
    if args:
        args[0]()                    
    #print("after",self.counter)
    self.counter=self.counter+1
    result1=[perm.count(z) for z in perm]
    result1.sort(reverse=True)
    if result1[0]<=self.actual_repeat:
        yield perm
```

I am using itertools to generate the permutations , count each letter and find their fequency and filter for two letter words...the variable `self.actual repeat` is 2

Comment: Could you please give your code (I'm curious), not just your results?

Comment: A added the main part of my code..I am using itertools from python library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take a slightly more complex example: $5$ distinct characters, max $3$ of one kind:

You can have a number of possible patterns of string length $5$ (say):

$3-2,\quad 3-1-1,\quad2-2-1,\quad2-1-1-1,\quad$ and $\quad1-1-1-1-1$

The formula you can use is [Choose characters for pattern]$\times$[permute characters]

e.g. for the first pattern, $\binom51\binom41 \times \frac{5!}{3!2!}= 200$

and for the second pattern, $\binom51\binom42 \times \frac{5!}{3!1!1!!} = 600$

Note particularly $\binom42,\;not\; \binom41\binom31$ for the second pattern,
as choosing $aaabc$ and $aaacb$ are the same , the order in which we choose $b$ and $c$ doesn't matter.

For your particular example, only $2$ patterns are possible:
$2-1:\; \binom31\binom21 \times \frac{3!}{2!1!} = 18$
$1-1-1:\; \binom33 \times \frac{3!}{1!1!1!} = 6$
Adding up, ans = $24$

---

ADDED MATERIAL to make computation more mechanical, using multinomial coefficients:

Note down the **frequencies** of triples, doubles, singles, and non-occurrences for each pattern,
e.g. for the pattern $3-1-1$, there is $1$ triple, $2$ singles, $2$ non-occurrences so the multinomial coefficient for **choosing** letters will be $\binom{5}{1,2,2}$ and that for permuting the pattern will be $\binom{5}{3,1,1}$ which is the same as $\frac{5!}{3!1!1!}$

For my example, you can now mechanically compute and add up:

$3-2: \binom5{1,1,3}\binom5{3,2}$
$3-1-1: \binom5{1,2,2}\binom5{3,1,1}$
$2-2-1: \binom5{2,1,2}\binom5{2,2,1}$
$2-1-1-1: \binom5{1,3,1}\binom5{2,1,1,1}$
$1-1-1-1-1:\binom55\binom5{1,1,1,1,1}$

Comment: can you explain "3−2,3−1−1,2−2−1,2−1−1−1, and 1−1−1−1−1" I am a little slow..thanks

Comment: 3-2 means 3 of one character, 2 of another, e.g. for the character set {a,b,c,d,e}, aaabb aaacc, aaadd, aaaee, bbbaa,bbbcc,bbbdd, bbbee, cccaa,cccbb, cccdd, cccee, dddaa,dddbb,dddcc,dddee, eeeaa,eeebb,eeecc and eeedd . Similarly, 3-1-1 means 3 of one character, and 1 each of two other characters, e.g. aaabc, aaabd, aaabe, aaacd, aaace, aaade,  similarly others having bbb, ccc, ddd, eee as the triple with one each of two other characters.

Comment: excellent..let me write a script to test this approach and if all went well..I will accept this answer...

Comment: the generator generates permutation which the order of each letter matters..can you add some more detail with this revelation in mind

Comment: But you wanted that, didn't you ? Your example of 24 is one of generated permutations. I will shortly include added material that will make the computation more mechanical.

Comment: thanks...last question....when I sum up I got 5,520 is this correct?

Comment: For my example, case by case, $20\cdot10+30\cdot20+30\cdot30+20\cdot60+1\cdot120=3020$

Comment: I think I am using the wrong formula at this document...http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/don/courses/math1904/lect08.pdf.....Can you direct me to the formula for you are using?

Comment: looking at the first pattern "3-1" ..how did you get 20 as the results for  (5 1,1)? when I use the formula n!/(r1!*r2!)..I get 120...need some help...thank you

Comment: Look at this image at this link.....http://crazycodes.org/images/question.png ....you will find what I am trying to resolve..I am sorry I am giving you some extra work here but I really need your help ........

Comment: Maybe I should have given the **full** form of the multinomials, which include the count of characters with zero occurrence. It is understood that the lower indices must sum up to the upper index, so when I abbreviate as $\binom5{1,1}$, it is a short form of $\binom5{1,1,3}$ which is $\frac{5!}{1!1!3!} = 20$. I am shortly editing my answer lest it misleads.

Comment: where are you my friend..your answer worked like a charm..I ask another question which is a variation to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899238/number-of-arrangements-of-red-blue-and-green-balls-in-which-a-maximum-of-three#1899238  can you solve or provide sugesstion..?thanks buddy

Comment: do you know anythin about bell polynomial / triangle?..I found this article that derives a formula on how to use it but It requires some great skills in understanding the concept  http://ac.els-cdn.com/S002198006680025X/1-s2.0-S002198006680025X-main.pdf?_tid=54718176-67fc-11e6-8862-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1471824592_1b30147d6b09d53cc428eed0b8cefcdb

Comment: I think you could refer it to lulu in the other question, I am only a dabbler in this field.

Answer (score 0):

For strings from $\{a,b,c\}$ of length $3$ the answer is simple. Take all the permutations (there are $3^3$) and subtract the number that have more than two of a single letter. In this case there are $3$, one triple for each letter.

$$3^3 - 3 = 24$$

As the next example, suppose we have strings of length $7$ from $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ where we can't have more that $3$ of a single letter. There are $7^5$ strings without any restrictions. Now we need to subtract out the number of strings with $4, 5, 6,$ or $7$ of the same letter. A word with $4$ of the same letter will be a permutation of a set of one of the following forms:

$$\{w,w,w,w,x,y,z\} \text{ or } \{w,w,w,w,x,x,y\} \text{ or } \{w,w,w,w,x,x,x\}$$

where $w,x,y,z$ represent some choice of four letters from $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$. Now for the first form, there are $5$ choices for $w$, $\binom{4}{3}$ choices for $x,y,z$, and $\binom{7}{4}$ permutations of $\{w,w,w,w,x,y,z\}$.

(See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73626/trouble-in-finding-number-of-permutations) for details on the last part of the previous sentence).

Thus the number of strings with exactly $4$ of the same letter is

$$5\cdot\binom{4}{3}\cdot\binom{7}{4,1,1,1} = \frac{5 \cdot 4! \cdot 7!}{3! \cdot 4!} = 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 4200$$

Similarly, for $\{w,w,w,w,x,x,y\}$ and $\{w,w,w,w,x,x,x\}$ we have

$$5\cdot\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{7}{4,2,1} = \frac{5 \cdot 4! \cdot 7!}{2! \cdot 4! \cdot 2!} = 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 6300$$

and

$$5\cdot\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{7}{4,3} = \frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 7!}{4! \cdot 3!} = 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot 5 = 700$$

Putting this all together so far,

$$5 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^3 \binom{4}{i}\binom{7}{4,4-i}$$

[... Running out of time for now. Will return later ... ]