# Number of arrangements of red, blue, and green balls in which a maximum of three balls of the same color are placed in the five slots

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, combinations

[image]

From the picture above I have five slots and a bag of balls (three) of color -red, blue and green...

Question

Now whenever I choose a ball, I note the colour and replace it in the bag, then I randomly keep choosing balls (independent event) until all five slots are filled and put them back in the bag..

How can I derive a formula to find all possible repetitive arrangements (exhaustive approach) **with the condition** that a MAXIMUM of THREE balls of the same color are in the five slots.

**Note:**

I have ask a similar question at [Finding the Total number of permutation using a selective formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897267/finding-the-total-number-of-permutation-using-a-selective-formula/1897348?noredirect=1#comment3895323_1897348)

In the accepted answer, there were **five** slots and **five** letters and all arrangements with a maximum of three letters were found **using a pattern**

$3-1-1: \binom5{1,2,2}\binom5{3,1,1}$
$2-2-1: \binom5{2,1,2}\binom5{2,2,1}$
$2-1-1-1: \binom5{1,3,1}\binom5{2,1,1,1}$
$1-1-1-1-1:\binom55\binom5{1,1,1,1,1}$

Now in this question the number of balls and slots varies

I would like to build from the **pattern** above answer using multinomials (since I don't want to write a  new algorithm again)

Comment: I don't think this is clear.  What do the slots have to do with anything?  Are you saying that when you note a color you write it in one of the slots, UNLESS doing so would violate the cap rule?   But then...why not just ask "how many words on $\{R,B,G\}$ are there of length $5$ with no letter appearing more than $3$ times?"

Comment: yes I would like "how many words on {R,B,G} are there of length 5 with no letter appearing more than 3 times?"

Comment: @lulu note too order/arrangements counts

Answer (score 2):

We will solve the problem:  "how many words of length $5$ on $\{R,B,G\}$ are there in which no letter appears more than $3$ times".

Easier to work backwards.  Without the cap rule there are $3^5$ possible words.

How many of these have exactly $4\;R's$?  Well there are $5$ place to put the non-$R$, and $2$ options for what letter it is.  Hence $10$.  As there are three letter, there are exactly $30$ words of length $5$ in which some letter appears exactly $4$ times.

Now, of course there are eactly $3$ words in which a letter appears $5$ times.

Hence there are $30+3=33$ words of length $5$ in which some letter appears more than $3$ times.

It follows that there are $3^5-33=\fbox {210}$ words of length $5$ in which no letter appears more than $3$ times.

Answer (score 0):

Came across it just now !
Since you wanted the same method, here it is.
Actually, you want to put five letters in **three** slots, which makes it easier than the answer you cited.

$3-2-0: \binom{3}{1,1,1}\binom{5}{3,2,0} = 60$

$3-1-1: \binom{3}{1,2}\binom{5}{3,1,1} = 60$

$2-2-1: \binom{3}{2,1}\binom{5}{2,2,1} = 90 \Rightarrow \boxed{210}$

---

**Added Material**

If you were thinking of programming it, the simplest way would be to use exponential generating functions, and find the coefficient of $x^5$ in $\;5!(x^0 + x^1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!})^3$,
the coefficients indicating that a particular letter has been used $0-3$ times, with correction for multiple use of a letter by division by the appropriate factorials to get the same [answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coefficient+of+x%5E5+in+5%21%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2F2%21+%2B+x%5E3%2F3%21%29%5E3)
viz.  $\boxed{210}$